# EFCore, keeping entity after disposing of scope/context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Im having troubles figuring out how to keep an entity after disposing of a scope:

```
public async Task<Camera> GetCamera(string cameraGuid)
{
    DirectCamera directCamera;
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var _accessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CamerasAccessor>(); 
        //CameraAccessor is just a DbContext, registered with `services.AddDbContext<CamerasAccessor>();`
        directCamera = _accessor.Cameras.Single(can => can.Id == cameraGuid);

        return directCamera;
    }
}
```

This ofc won't work cause the accessor/dbcontext will be disposed, with all proxies included, before the value will be handled.

My question is: "How can I keep/get entity without it being wrapped in a proxy, that wont be disposed as soon as the scope will be disposed?"

My first thought was to use `AsNoTracking()` but that doesnt give you a non proxy object.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The using block causes object to be disposed.

Comment: `DirectCamera` isn't a proxy, surely? Do you mean navigation properties within it? And you've enabled lazy loading (as this isn't enabled by default)? Perhaps [eagerly loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) these would work.

Comment: @jdweng As I said, I know, but how can I keep it from getting disposed? I need to keep the object to send it to the clients.

Comment: Why do you create scope explicitly? ASP.NET controller is doing that for every request and disposes scope exactly after result serialization.

Comment: Either remove the using block or put the send code inside the using.

Comment: @CharlesMager Ah, I forgot about that. Yeah, thats for sure the problem. I was using LazyLoading in an earlier draft and forgot about this.

Comment: `ASP.NET` has it's own [`desposing mechanism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). so you needn't to handle it manually unless its became obvious where reuired. So I think you have got the point and able to figureout that isn't?